# How to append a list's elements to a list in R quickly?

Tags: r, optimization

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
m <- as.data.frame.matrix(matrix(c(20, 32, 52, 84, 98, 101), ncol = 2, nrow = 3))
ages <- as.numeric()
for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
  ages <- c(ages, c(m$V1[i]:m$V2[i]))
}
```

Essentially, the first column is the starting age, and the second column is the ending age. I'm trying to append every single age from start to end for every individual into a list. Unfortunately, this is very slow since I have around a million observations, and I'm looking for a way to optimize.

Comment: `unlist(apply(m, MAR = 1, function(x)x[1]:x[2]))`?

Comment: Could you add a "visual"(copy-paste) of your expected output?

Comment: @NelsonGon I'm looking for something like (20, 21, 22, 23, ... 82, 83, 84, 32,33,34,...,96, 97, 98, 50, 51, 52,..., 99, 100, 101), so yes, same numbers will be repeated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `mapply` and create sequence between two columns

```
unlist(mapply(`:`, m$V1, m$V2))

#[1]    20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37..
#[29]   48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65..
#[57]   76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40..
#[85]   51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68..
#[113]  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96..
#[141]  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77 ..
#[169]  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
set_names(m, c('from', 'to')) %>%
     pmap(., seq) %>% 
     unlist
```

---

Or using `Map` from `base R`

```
unlist(do.call(Map, c(f = `:`, m)))
```